# CSRF verification failed. request aborted, nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, http-status-code-404, passport.js

I have implemented SSO with passport using nodejs, and upon logging in (azure ad login) I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAgus.png)

here's my code:

```
 var SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;

passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
  {
    path: '/login/callback',
    entryPoint: 'https://myapps.microsoft.com/signin/SAML-...-DEV...',
    issuer: '...'
  },
  
  function(profile, done) {
    findByEmail(profile.email, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      return done(null, user);
      
    });
  })
);

app.post('/login/callback',
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('inside /login/callback')
    //after login, goes here, but renders back to login/callback. then back here.
   res.render('index.ejs')
  }
);


app.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
      console.log("inside azuread /login get passport saml")
     res.render('index.ejs')
  }
);
```

please let me know if anyone has ran into this before! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hey, any solution you have found, thanks